# mysql Stored procedure keep on running -when triggered from a shell script

Tags: mysql, procedure

This mysql Stored procedure is running fine when executed through workbench , but never finishes when called through a shell script .What to do here?

Running this in  version 5.7.35-0ubuntu.Here the Procedure and the shell script,

```html
DELIMITER 

USE  db1; 

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  sp ;

CREATE  PROCEDURE  sp ()
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  db1.sp_test;
 CREATE TABLE db1.sp_test
 (
     account_number  VARCHAR(50),
     insurance  VARCHAR(150),
     other_charges VARCHAR(50),
     REFUND VARCHAR(50),
     Processing_Fee  VARCHAR(50),
     payment VARCHAR(50),
     payment_1 VARCHAR(50),
     Sec  VARCHAR(50),
     amount   VARCHAR(50),
     difference  VARCHAR(50),
    .......
    ......
    Col_N   TEXT    
    );


INSERT INTO db1.sp_test 
    SELECT 
    account_number  VARCHAR(50),
    insurance,
    other_charges,
     REFUND VARCHAR(50),
     Processing_Fee  VARCHAR(50),
     payment VARCHAR(50),
     payment_1 VARCHAR(50),
     Sec  VARCHAR(50),
     amount   VARCHAR(50),
     difference  VARCHAR(50),
    .......
    .......
    Col_N
 FROM  db1.table_1  ad
LEFT JOIN  db2.table_2 cm ON cm.account_number=ad.account_number 
LEFT JOIN  db1.table_3  ds ON ds.loan_acc_no=ad.account_number 
 WHERE   
  cm.date   BETWEEN
 DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))- 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(NOW());
  
    
  CREATE INDEX acc ON db1.sp_test( account_number , transaction_date );
    
  UPDATE db1.sp_test sp , db2.table_2  t2
 SET sp.insurance  = ROUND(t2.amount)
WHERE t2.transaction='TEST_TRANSACTION' AND 
t2.account_number=sp.account_number;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db1.temp_1;

CREATE TABLE db1.temp_1
SELECT account_number, penal_interest,acc_fee,preclosure_fee  
FROM  db1.table_1  ds
WHERE account_number IN (SELECT account_number FROM db1.sp_test);

UPDATE db1.sp_test sp,db1.temp_1 ds
     SET other_charges =ROUND(penal_interest+acc_fee+preclosure_fee )
    WHERE  ds.account_number=sp.account_number;


UPDATE db1.sp_test sp , db2.table_2  t2
 SET sp.REFUND  = t2.amount
WHERE t2.transaction='REFUND' AND 
t2.account_number=sp.account_number;

UPDATE db1.sp_test sp , db2.table_2  t2
 SET sp.Sec  = (0.01 * t2.amount )
WHERE t2.account_type LIKE 'Loan%'
 AND t2.account_number=sp.account_number;
 
 UPDATE db1.sp_test ad 
 SET   ad.payment  =
   ad.amount - (ad.Insurance+ad.Processing_Fee+ad.REFUND+ad.Sec); 
   
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db1.temp_2 ;
   
   CREATE TABLE db1.temp_2 
SELECT  ds.acc_no,ds.amount,ds.status
FROM  db1.table_3  ds
WHERE  ds.acc_no IN (SELECT sp.account_number FROM db1.sp_test sp) AND     ds.status ='Success' ;

UPDATE db1.sp_test sp ,db1.temp_2 temp
 SET sp.Payment_1  = temp.amount
WHERE temp.loan_acc_no=sp.account_number ;
   


COMMIT;

      
END

DELIMITER ;
```

*********************shell script *********************************************

#!/bin/bash

```
s_date=$(date "+%d%b%Y")
s_time=$(date "+%T")
echo "======================================"
echo "Process Started Date ${s_date} and Time ${s_time}"
echo "======================================"

echo "Removing old CSV file"
rm -rf /apps/data/mysqlbackup/*.csv


echo "=============================================================="
echo "sp_test table process started"
echo "=============================================================="

mysql -h 10.10.10.10 -P 61306 -uuser_name -pPassword DB_Name -B -e 
"call sp();"

mysql -h 10.10.10.10 -P 61306 -uuser_name -pPassword DB_Name -B -e 
"select * from sp_test;" > /apps/data/mysqlbackup/sp_test.csv

echo "sp_test process end"


c_date=$(date "+%d%b%Y")
c_time=$(date "+%T")
echo "=============================================================="
echo "Process Complete Date ${c_date} and Time ${c_time}"
echo "=============================================================="
```

Comment: *but never finishes when called through a shell script .* Show this "calling" code in details.

Comment: As previous comment said you should post your shell script . Have you tried  executing other commands in `MySQL` using this script  ?

Comment: Added the shell script. Was trying to execute the stored procedure from the shell and export the data populated as a csv file.

Comment: There is a syntax error, in the update statement, in your stored procedure.

Comment: @Luuk could you pls help me to get the update with syntax error.

Comment: Since my comment you have done 3 edits, so I will not comment on the error there was...

Comment: What are the other ways to achieve the same logic in the procedure.? Means other ways to rewrite the procedure.